# Apart from place names, are there any Native American words used in English?

Tags: etymology, vocabulary

Apart from place names, are there any Native American words used in English?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[Mark Rosenfelder](http://www.zompist.com/indianwd.html) has a list.  So too does [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_from_indigenous_languages_of_the_Americas)

Here is a partial selection of those which I might use

**Words from Algonquian languages:**
Caribou 
Chipmunk 
Eskimo 
Hickory 
Hominy 
Husky 
Moccasin 
Moose 
Mugwump 
Muskrat 
Opossum 
Papoose 
Pecan 
Pemmican 
Persimmon 
Powwow 
Raccoon 
Skunk 
Squash 
Squaw 
Terrapin 
Toboggan 
Tomahawk 
Totem
Wampum 
Wigwam 
Woodchuck

**Words from Nahuatl:**
Avocado 
Cacao/cocoa 
Chicle 
Chili 
Chocolate 
Coyote 
Guacamole 
Mesquite 
Mezcal 
Ocelot 
Peyote 
Shack 
Tomato

**Words from Quechua:**
Coca 
Cocaine 
Condor 
Guano 
Inca 
Jerky 
Llama 
Pampa 
Puma 
Quinine 
Vicuña

**Words from Eskimo-Aleut languages:**
Anorak 
Igloo 
Kayak

**Words from Arawakan languages:**
Barbecue 
Cacique 
Caiman 
Canoe 
Cassava 
Cay 
Guava 
Hammock 
Hurricane 
Iguana 
Maize 
Mangrove 
Papaya 
Potato 
Savanna 
Tobacco 
Yuca

**Words from Tupi-Guaraní languages:**
Cashew 
Cayenne 
Cougar 
Jaguar 
Maraca 
Macaw 
Petunia 
Piranha 
Tapioca 
Tapir 
Toucan

**Words from other indigenous languages of the Americas:**
Abalone 
Alpaca 
Bayou 
Cannibal 
Chinook 
Coypu 
Manatee 
Poncho 
Potlatch 
Sequoia 
Sockeye

Comment: +1 for this very exhaustive list.  I missed quite a few of them it appears !!

Answer (score 27):

#### Everyday English

- **tuxedo** - the etymology<sup>**1**</sup> is worth citing in extenso.

> 1889, named for Tuxedo Park, N.Y.,
>   site of a country club where it first
>   was worn in 1886. The name is an
>   attractive subject for elaborate
>   speculation, e.g.:
>
> The Wolf tribe in New York was called in scorn by other Algonquians
>    from **tuksit**: *round foot*, implying that they
>   easily fell down in surrender. In
>   their region thus came the names
>   **Tuxedo** and **Tuxedo Lake**, which were
>   acquired by the Griswold family in
>   payment of a debt. There the family
>   established the exclusive **Tuxedo Club**,
>   and there in the late 1880s Griswold
>   Lorillard first appeared in a *dinner
>   jacket without tails*, a *tuxedo*. By a
>   twist of slang, one may now refer to a
>   man in a tuxedo as a 'wolf. [Shipley]
>
> But in another version of the story,
>   p'tuksit was the Algonquian word for
>   "wolf," the animal, perhaps from the
>   shape of its paws. The authoritative
>   Bright, however, says the tribe's name
>   probably is originally a place name,
>   perhaps Munsee Delaware (Algonquian)
>   p'tuck-sepo "crooked river." Short
>   form tux is attested from 1922.

#### Animals

- **skunk** - meaning "urinating fox".

  > Algonquian language (probably Abenaki)
  >   seganku, from Proto-Algonquian
  >   */šeka:kwa/, from */šek-/ "to urinate" + */-a:kw/ "fox."
- **cariboo** - meaning "scratcher"

  > caribou, from Micmac (Algonquian)
  >   kaleboo, lit. "pawer, scratcher," from
  >   its kicking snow aside to feed on moss
  >   and grass, or a related Algonquian
  >   name
- **opossum** - meaning "white animal".

  > from Powhatan (Algonquian) apasum
  >   "white animal."
- **wampum** - meaning "string of white". (credits to @The Raven)

  > shortened from wampumpeag (1620s),
  >   from Algonquian (probably
  >   Narragansett) wanpanpiak "string of
  >   white (shell beads)," from wab "white" + ompe "string" + pl. suffix -ag.

#### Plants

- **Squash** (pumpkin) - meaning "green things that may be eaten raw"

  > Shortened borrowing from Narraganset
  >   (Algonquian) askutasquash, lit. "the
  >   green things that may be eaten raw,"
  >   from askut "green, raw" + asquash
  >   "eaten

#### For Native Americans **everyday life** items

- **squaw**,

  > from Massachuset (Algonquian) squa
  >   "woman" (cf. also Narraganset squaws
  >   "woman")
- **papoose**,

  > from Narragansett (Algonquian) papoos
  >   "child," lit. "very young."
- **wigwam**

  > from Algonquian (probably Eastern
  >   Abenaki) wikewam "a dwelling," said to
  >   mean lit. "their house;" also said to
  >   be found in such formations as wikiwam
  >   and Ojibwa wiigiwaam and Delaware
  >   wiquoam

<sup>**1**: All etymologies cited from etymonline.</sup>

Comment: @The Raven, thx I added "wampum" to the Animals category. Thx.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the information given above, there is a book-length treatment of this subject in:

Cutler, Charles L. *[O Brave New Words: Native American loanwords in current English](http://books.google.com/books?id=83CIggbRi8YC&dq=o%20brave%20new%20worlds%20native%20american&source=gbs_navlinks_s)*. Norman : University of Oklahoma Press, 1994. 286 pages.

It's an enjoyable read.

Answer (score 4):

**Muckamuck**, **high muckamuck**, or **high muckity muck**, a not flattering slang term for an important person.  It comes from **Hiu muckamuck**, a Chinook jargon phrase that means "plenty to eat."